# R - consolidate missing data in multiple columns

Tags: r

Say that you have a data frame named `df` with 25 columns, first of them being named `ID`, second to thirteenth having names from `A1` to `A12` and fourteenth to twenty-fifth having names from `B1` to `B12`. Values in the A and B variables can be missing data.

The task that I am facing is to consolidate the missingness in the data - if there is a missing entry in, say, 8th row of A4, then the 8th row of B4 also needs to be updated to NA, even if it has some data. This also works vice versa, if there is a missing entry in, say, 19th row of B11, then the 19th row of A11 also needs to be missing.

I can do this with two `for` loops:

```
for(i in 2:13){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(is.na(df[j,i+12])){
      df[j,i] <- NA
    }
  }
}

for(i in 14:25){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(is.na(df[j,i-12])){
      df[j,i] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am looking for a solution that doesn't include `for` loops and is preferrably in tidyverse. How could this be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could pivot to long format, then in a given row that contains `NA`, replace all values by `NA`, then pivot back to wide:

```
spec <- 
  df %>% 
  build_longer_spec(cols = -ID,
                    names_to = c(".value", "set"),
                    names_pattern = "(.+)(\\d+)",
                    values_to = "value")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer_spec(spec) %>% 
  print() %>% 
  # Intermediary long format:
  #> # A tibble: 6 x 4
  #>      ID set       A     B
  #>   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
  #> 1     1 1         1    NA
  #> 2     1 2         4    10
  #> 3     2 1         2     8
  #> 4     2 2         5    NA
  #> 5     3 1         3     9
  #> 6     3 2        NA    12
  rowwise(ID, set) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~ ifelse(any(is.na(c_across(everything()))), NA, .x))) %>% 
  pivot_wider_spec(spec)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      ID    A1    A2    B1    B2
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    NA     4    NA    10
#> 2     2     2    NA     8    NA
#> 3     3     3    NA     9    NA
```

---

With sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:3,
  A1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  A2 = c(4, 5, NA),
  B1 = c(NA, 8, 9),
  B2 = c(10, NA, 12)
)
df
#>   ID A1 A2 B1 B2
#> 1  1  1  4 NA 10
#> 2  2  2  5  8 NA
#> 3  3  3 NA  9 12
```

Comment: Great answer. I thought of the exact same thing, but this is 100% cleaner than my approach.

Comment: Only thing I got going in mine is that mine is twice as fast to execute.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't run benchmarks, I don't expect it to be fast. I guess it's a tradeoff of readability and performance for the OP to decide. But if performance is of the essence, I'd expect my other answer to perform better :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#create dataset
library(tidyverse)
library(missForest)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10))
df[paste0("a", 1:10)] <- lapply(1:10, function(x) rnorm(10, x))
df[paste0("b", 1:10)] <- lapply(1:10, function(x) rnorm(10, x))
df <- bind_cols(df[1], missForest::prodNA(df[-1], noNA = 0.2)) #add NAs
df
```

`purrr::map` over variables:

```
df[paste0("a", 1:10)] <- map2(df %>% select(starts_with("a")), df %>% select(starts_with("b")),
                                                   ~ ifelse(is.na(.y), NA, .x))
df[paste0("b", 1:10)] <- map2(df %>% select(starts_with("b")), df %>% select(starts_with("a")),
                              ~ ifelse(is.na(.y), NA, .x))
df
```

Answer (score 1):

We could create masks of the NA values in both sub-tables, combine them, and apply them back to both sub-tables:

```
na_mask <- is.na(df[2:13]) | is.na(df[14:25])

df[2:13][na_mask] <- NA
df[14:25][na_mask] <- NA
```

Comment: I too tried to get this to work, and didn't think of it in that way. Perfect solution right here!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the suggested solution should be sufficiently performant. Looping over the columns is really not a big deal.

Thanks for voting up and accepting as answer if you like it.

```
# Create data
nrows <- 10
ncols <- 25
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:(nrows*ncols), nrow = nrows))
colnames(df1) <- c(
  "ID",
  paste0("A", 1:12),
  paste0("B", 1:12)
)

df1[1:3, c("A1")] <- NA
df1[5:7, c("B5")] <- NA

# Prepare calculation
cols <- as.list(as.data.frame(
  matrix(c(paste0("A", 1:12),
           paste0("B", 1:12)), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))

# Do calculation
for (col in cols) {
  missing <- is.na(rowSums(df1[col]))
  df1[missing, col] <- NA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution that showcases some advantages of reformatting one's data.

Let me first generate some data (since we received none)

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample_nrows <- 10
full_df <- 
  tibble(
    ID = rep(seq_len(sample_nrows), each = 12 + 12),
    name = c(str_c("A", 1:12),
             str_c("B", 1:12)) %>%
      rep(sample_nrows),
    value = 
      rgamma(
        n = 12 * 2 * sample_nrows,
        shape = sample.int(20, size = 10)
      ) %>% 
      round())

full_df %>% 
  #' add 10% missingness
  mutate(value = if_else(rbinom(n(), size = 1, prob = 0.1) %>% as.logical(), NA_real_, value)) %>% 
  #' reconstruct into wide-format
  pivot_wider() %>%
  print(n = Inf, width = Inf) ->
  partial_df
```

Thus, we generate `gamma`-distributed data, for `sample_nrows`-rows (that's `full_df`), and we add 10% missing data to the whole thing and call it `partial_df`.

This formatting gives us a novel idea. Working with the long-format will give this result...

```r
partial_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(name, c("name", "var_id"), regex = "(\\D+)(\\d+)") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name") %>% 
  mutate(
    both_na = is.na(A) | is.na(B),
    A = if_else(both_na, NA_real_, A),
    B = if_else(both_na, NA_real_, B),
    both_na = NULL
  ) -> partial_df_with_NAs
```

To get back to the original format:

```r
partial_df_with_NAs %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var_id, values_from = c(A,B), names_sep = "") %>% 
  print(n = Inf, width = Inf)
```